# in python - why size of the variable in the memory diminish after many runs?

Tags: python, memory, bots, telegram

i've wrote a python bot (for telegram) that runs infinitely in a loop and its goal is to load the content of a particular page , to search for a certain sentences and words using the below code:

```
response = requests.get(url)
content = response.content.decode("utf8")

for m in re.finditer("words to find", content):
```

at first every things looks perfect but after about 20 to 30 request to my bot it cant load the page source thoroughly and fails to finding the words so:

before the 20 iteration the size of the variable (content) in the memory is 39546
but then the size is diminished to 2636

```
getsizeof(content)
```

Comment: Have you tried printing the content or writing it to files for review? My guess would be an error response is being returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print what's in content. Most probably your bot is being blocked and being handed over a captcha page or something like that. You could also check the status code for clues as well.

You might also want to add a breakpoint after some number or requests and inspect variables. Check `ipdb` for that.

Comment: This answer is not worthy of "answer" status, more of a comment.

Comment: @randomir Why is it not? Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer `Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful`.

Comment: The question may be unclear, but you don't really answer it here. You are merely speculating and guessing the possible reasons, guiding the OP how to debug his problem.

Comment: yes that was the reason the page i was request was google search result and after many tries my ip was blocked..thanks